# Displaying Data in The ListView in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am retrieving data from SQLite and trying to display it in the ListView. The problem is I have two columns in the database and the listview only shows data from one column. I am using following code for this purpose

```
public List<entry> getAllEntries() {
    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ENTRIES,
            allEntries, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Entry entry = cursorToEntry(cursor);
        Entry entry1 = cursorToEntry(cursor);
        Log.d(TAG, "get entry = " + cursorToEntry(cursor).toString());
        entries.add(entry);


        cursor.moveToNext();

        Log.d(TAG, "get amount = "+ cursorToEntries(cursor).toString1());

        entries.add(entry1);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
            cursor.close();
    return entries;
}
```

And I have also been trying following code

```
while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        entries.add("Entry"+cursor.getString(1)+"Amount"+cursor.getString(2));
    }
```

And thats how I am displaying it in the ListView

```
List<Entry> values = datasource.getAllEntries();

    ArrayAdapter<Entry> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Entry>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: can you post your code that how are you displaying listview.

Comment: It is showing just one element because you are using predefined layout. Either you need to write custom adapter or use SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] { "name","id" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1,
   android.R.id.text2 });

// list should be hashmap to work properly.

Comment: Which list to be mentioned here? List<Entry>, gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a CursorAdapter, which lets you specify a row layout as well as how to map from columns in the cursor to views in the layout; or you can write your own adapter implementation that extends from BaseAdapter and is internally backed by a Cursor. I suggest you watch [The World of ListView](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&ei=IcODU-fLHou8oQTl4oLoDw&usg=AFQjCNGAklAgezvQNN0PVmomzRjd7ci2uQ&sig2=XZ2RvumKkBM7Y3O-rlAxsQ).